# How can I simplify the formula in R?

Tags: r, stata

I want to estimate a set formulas in R by systemfit,for each formula,it's mathmatic expression can be written as
https://www.mathcha.io/editor/VQKXXuLvCjWClxjyy4Ie0xBKOC1eN3lgCMMXdgG

In stata ,I can handle it by

```
gen double `lnap' = `a0' + `a1'*`lnp1' + `a2'*`lnp2' + `a3'*`lnp3' + `a4'*`lnp4' + `a5'*`lnp5' + `a6'*`lnp6'
forvalues i = 1/6 {
    forvalues j = 1/6 {
        replace `lnap' = `lnpindex' + 0.5*`g`i'`j''*`lnp`i''*`lnp`j''
        }
    }

gen double `bp' = 0
forvalues i = 1/6 {
    replace `bp' = `bofp' + `lnp`i''*`b`i''
}

replace `w1' = (`a1' + `g11'*`lnp1' + `g12'*`lnp2' + `g13'*`lnp3' + `g14'*`lnp4' + `g15'*`lnp5' + `g16'*`lnp6' + ///
`b1'*(`lnm' - `lnap') + `l1'/`bp'*(`lnm' - `lnap')^2 + `z1'*`eta11' + `z2'*`eta21' + `z3'*`eta31' + `z4'*`eta41'+ `z5'*`eta51'
```

I have read manuel for formula,it seems that the only way is to simplify this equation.I wonder if you can tell me how to write this complex equation to formula in R?
Many thanks!

Comment: In `R`, a `for` cycle is not necessary for `sum`. By default, `sum` will sum all values in the vector or matrix input. I cannot help you specifically, as the variable names in the strata code do not match those in the equation and I'm not familiar with strata to be able to parse it without matches. Can you edit your question to include some data in the respective variables and what the result should be?

Comment: It is often better to say what you want to do directly rather than expect people to be familiar with another language as well as that you're asking about. Here it seems likely that in your Stata code. `lnpindex` is a typo for `lnap` and `bofp` is a typo for `bp`. If not, then it is hard to know what you are doing.